# UItableview shared view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'd like to know if someone there in the community has ever implemented 2 UItableView in on single view, I've searched a lot trough google but i'm not sure if I'm using the correct words. What I need is lo look like as the Facebook menu where shows 2 table views, here is an screenshot of my idea. Any ideas/tutorials/blogs you can provide me will be useful, Thanks a lot!

http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/119/Purple/eb/62/0a/mzl.uvhmahke.320x480-75.jpg

Comment: Are you looking for how to have different sections in a UITableview? That is what the image looks like

Comment: yep its sections... not multiple uitableviews

Comment: hi guys, yes, thats why I wasnt so sure how to call them. But yes I'm looking how to implement UItableView in sections, do you have any info that can point me in the right direction? thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView` is simply a subclass of `UIScrollView`, which is a subclass of `UIView`, so, yes, you should be able to have more than one tableView in a single view.  The only 'gotcha' with this is that your `delegate` and `datasource` callback methods for the table views need to either be broken out explicitly in each method (using `if(tableView.tag == 0)` or something) or either have completely different objects be the datasource and delegate callback methods.  The tableviews don't care where they are located.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(tableView.tag == 0){
        //do something for first tableView
    }
    else{
        //do something for other tableView
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The image you posted does not have two tableViews in a single view.  It looks like there are two tableViews in two separate views, which would more than likely have completely different `delegate` and `datasource`s.